# PHP & RabbitMQ & execute remote controller that will download data by curl from other web server

Tags: curl, rabbitmq, phalcon

I Have some minor problem. I have a controller and action written on phalcon, which is accessible by address http://localhost/download/data/(1-5000). What it does it connects with curl to a website and writes data to a database. As the volume of info is great, I run a cycle that puts all these separate jobs to the queue manager RabbitMQ giving a page_id as parameter.
I have been able to put all 5000 jobs to the queue and have created a script that should utilize these jobs but for some reason, it does not work because if it worked it would have created entries in the database.
The php file is **Listener.php**

```
<?php
require_once( __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;

ob_start();
$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('localhost', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
if (!$connection) {
    die("no connection");
}
$channel = $connection->channel();
$channel->queue_declare('HelloTime', false, false, false, false);
echo " [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C\n";
$callback = function ($pg) {
     echo ' [x] Received ', $pg->body, "\n";
     $page = $pg->body;
     header('Location: http://localhost/download/data/'.$page.'');
};
$channel->basic_consume('HelloTime', '', false, true, false, false, $callback);
while (count($channel->callbacks)) {
    $channel->wait();
}
$this->fsockopen();
ob_end_flush();
```

so after creating a queue I run in a bash terminal `php Listener.php` where I can see that it's been executed and removed from the queue `sudo rabbitmqctl list_queue` shows from 5000 to 0, but there is no trail of execution on controller and action for some reasons I do not understand.

I used  `ob_start(); ob_end_flush();` to remove erros like `cannot modify header information`
The current curl download and database entry logic  are in Download controller written on Phalcon

Why does the callback fails to execute action on remote controller?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solved, I put another curl get request, which executes what is needed to be done

Comment: Could you please share your implementation of RabbitMQ with Phalcon?

Answer (score 0):

My implementation of putting queues on rabbitMQ with phalcon

```
 <php
    require_once(APP_PATH.'/vendor/autoload.php');
    use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;
    use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    set_time_limit(0);
    Class DownloadController extends ControllerBase
    {
    public function execute($page)
        {
            $connection = new AMQPStreamConnection(
                'localhost',    #host - host name where the RabbitMQ server is runing
                5672,           #port - port number of the service, 5672 is the default
                'guest',        #user - username to connect to server
                'guest'         #password
            );
            /** @var $channel AMQPChannel */
            $channel = $connection->channel();
            $channel->queue_declare(
                'HelloTime',    #queue name - Queue names may be up to 255 bytes of UTF-8 characters
                false,          #passive - can use this to check whether an exchange exists without modifying the server state
                false,          #durable - make sure that RabbitMQ will never lose our queue if a crash occurs - the queue will survive a broker restart
                false,          #exclusive - used by only one connection and the queue will be deleted when that connection closes
                false           #autodelete - queue is deleted when last consumer unsubscribes
            );
            $pg = new AMQPMessage($page);
            $channel->basic_publish(
                $pg,           #message
                '',             #exchange
                'HelloTime'     #routing key
            );
            $channel->close();
            $connection->close();
        }
        public function dataAction() {
            $page=5000;
            while ($page>=1) {
                $this->execute($page);
                $page--;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I"m using Beanstalkd and with your code I'll give it a try to RabbitMQ